# Angular: radiobuttons stop firing "ng-change" after each one was clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building radio buttons dynamically. `ng-change='newValue(value)` stops being called after each radio button has been pressed once.

this works: Clicking on the radio buttons changes the value to foo/bar/baz.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZPcSe/19/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="bar" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="baz" ng-change='newValue(value)'>    
<hr>
{{value}}
</div>
```

this code does not: The {{value}} - "label" is not updated once each radio button has been pressed at least once. Aparently ng-change is not fired any more.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2]">
    <input name="asdf" type="radio" ng-model="value" value={{i}} ng-change='newValue(value)'>   
    </span>
    {{value}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPcSe/18/

The Controlles is the same each time:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = '-';
    $scope.newValue = function(value) {
    $scope.value = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ngRepeat` [creates new scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat), so trying to set `value` sets it on the new scope. The workaround is to reference a property  on an object that is on the parent scope--the object lookup happens on the parent scope, and then changing the property works as expected:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<span ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2]">
  <input name="asdf" ng-model="options.value" value="{{i}}" type="radio">
</span>
{{options.value}}
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        value: '-'
    };
    $scope.newValue = function(value) {
        // $scope.options.value = value; // not needed, unless you want to do more work on a change
    }
}​
```

You can check out [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPcSe/20/) of this workaround. See [angular/angular.js#1100 on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1100) for more information.

Comment: This seems like magic - how and where is `$scope.newValue` called? There is no `ng-change` event specified in the HTML, so where does it fire?

Comment: @Richard It doesn't fire; it was a function in the original question, so I copied it over; I think the `console.log` was left in from some debugging on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick work-around, we can achieve the same- using `ng-model="$parent.value"`, because it would refer to the *parent of `ng-repeat` scope* i.e- **in `myCtrl` scope**

Only Change in `ng-model`-

```
<input name="asdf" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.value" value={{i}} ng-change='newValue(value)'>
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k84dfdcr/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try `ng-click` instead of `ng-change`.