# ng-change event firing only once inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here in my form, I am using two radio buttons and would like to check the selected values. But this does not work as expected. I would like to determine the individual radio selection value and display Big/Small in the Result column

```
<div ng-controller="CityCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Big</th>
      <th>Small</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="city in cities">
      <td>{{ city.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{city.name}}-{{$index}}" ng-model="big" value="big_value" ng-change="check(city.name, big)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{city.name}}-{{$index}}" ng-model="small" value="small_value" ng-change="check(city.name, small)">
      </td>
      <td>***</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('cityApp', []);

function CityCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.big = '';
  $scope.small = '';
  $scope.cities = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tokyo'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Guangzhou'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Seoul'
  }];

  $scope.check = function(city, value) {
    console.log("City->" + city + " ::: Value->" + value);
  };
}
```

From other answers I did infer a few things:

1. Understand Prototypical Inheritance in JS ?!
2. ng-repeat creates child scope that affects these radios inside ng-repeat
3. use $parent on ng-modal in the radio

I did played around, but couldn't make this work, I guess I am making some obvious mistake here.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mw2us37h/

NOTE:
I am not using ng-value but passing a hardcoded value.
Changing to ng-click doesnt work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-change event only fires once for each radio button when created with ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790239/ng-change-event-only-fires-once-for-each-radio-button-when-created-with-ng-repea)

Comment: Do you want multiple cities to be selected? or one city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what your trying. I think you like to display the radio button value in the result column and/or have a function on click where the value is passed.

**Display the radio button value in result column** 
I would change the ngModel value so it binds to something city specific. So change:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{city.name}}-{{$index}}" ng-model="big" value="big_value">
```

to:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{city.name}}-{{$index}}" ng-model="city.size" value="big_value">
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="{{city.name}}-{{$index}}" ng-model="small" value="small_value">
```

to

```
<input type="radio" name="{{city.name}}-{{$index}}" ng-model="city.size" value="small_value">
```

So the model points to the same variable `city.size`, this is where the selected value will be saved. Then change `***` in the result column to `city.size`
See changes fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2kxuyr7/

**Get value on ngClick**

Use ngChange as you allready do I would do it a bit different for simplicity. Change:

```
ng-change="check(city.name, whatEverValue)"
```

to: 
    ng-change="check(city)"

and the check function would look like:

```
  $scope.check = function(city) {
    console.log("City->" + city.name + " ::: Value->" + city.size);
  };
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmszxj8s/ 
Then ngChange is fired on each change.

Comment: Also how could I retrieve a map of city:size from all the selected radios if I would want to collect this on a Submit button to process at the backend?

Comment: Here take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8dct8ptz/. Made a submit button that logs different type of post data. The last one is most map alike. city.id => city.size

Answer (score 2):

Flagged this as a duplicate, but it seems like the solution is to use `ng-click` instead of `ng-change` when working with radio buttons in angularjs.

Here is an edit of your fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/mw2us37h/1/

Comment: For now we had to use ng-change as ng-click causes problem in the UI as clicking on nearest label it triggers the click event...