# Angularjs unable to to bind radio buttons with model inside nested scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I'm unable to bind radio buttons with my model.In my code radio buttons are being created dynamically inside ng-repeat which is inside ng-if.Here is my code

```
 <div ng-if="Type.Value == 'Gadgets'">
    <div class="form-group radioChkBtn">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Device Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="radio" ng-repeat="type in Types">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="DeviceType" ng-value="{{type.Value}}"  id="radioDeviceType{{$index}}" name="devicetype"><label for="radioDeviceType{{$index}}"> {{type.Value}}</label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Value of DeviceType is always undefined.Even when I assign it some value none of the radio buttons is selected.ng-if creates a scope so is ng-repeat. May be it is the nesting of scopes which is causing the problem.Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you output {{DeviceType}}, does it have a value?  Also, unwrap your `{{type.Value}}` ... you don't need the `{{...}}` when using ng-value, only value.

Comment: As an aside, for input radios, I prefer to use `<label><input.../><span>text</span></label>` this way you can use `label > input + span` for custom radio glyphs.

Comment: @tracker1 yes when I output  DeviceType  it has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, try setting the model on radio select.

Have this in your controller:

```
$scope.onRadioChange = function(newValue) {
    $scope.DeviceType.value = newValue;
};
```

And make your HTML similar to this:

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="type in Types">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="DeviceType.value" ng-change="onRadioChange(type.Value)" ng-value="type.Value" id="{{type.Id}}" name="myRadios"><label for="{{type.Id}}"> {{type.Value}}</label>
</div>
```

So to break it down, we are now triggering the scope function `onRadioChange()` when the radio button is clicked via `ng-change`. We are passing the `type.value` to it, and inside the function making the model of `DeviceType.value` equal to the value that is passed to it.

In the example below, you can see that I output `DeviceType.value` on the page once a radio button is clicked and it has the same value as the radio button that is selected. I use `DeviceType.value` instead of just `DeviceType` to get around an Angular problem.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/vGwyGJ)

Comment: Fizzix the problem with your example is that once you have selected all the radio buttons one by one the change event does not fire any more.

Comment: @sqlcte - You're exactly right, nice find. I'll see if I can find a fix now and will get back to you.

Comment: @sqlcte - All fixed. Checkout my new comments on the post and the updated example. Simply just changed `DeviceType` to `DeviceType.value` and the model declaration of `DeviceType` is now an object like: `$scope.DeviceType = {value="nothing yet"};`

Comment: Thanks fizzix it worked this time but can you explain what could possibly the reason of it not working without a Value property.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443619/angular-radiobuttons-stop-firing-ng-change-after-each-one-was-clicked) sums it up well. They state "`ngRepeat` creates new scope, so trying to set value sets it on the new scope. The workaround is to reference a property on an object that is on the parent scope--the object lookup happens on the parent scope, and then changing the property works as expected".

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) { 
 
 $scope.devices = [{
  nameD: "Device 1"
  }, {
  nameD: "Device 2"
  }, {
  nameD: "Device 3"
  }, {
  nameD: "Device 4"
 }];
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="device in devices">  
 <label>{{device.nameD}} 
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.deviceType" value="{{device.nameD}}" />       
 </label>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
{{deviceType}}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has no relation to what the OP is asking at all? Your answer is relevant to form validation, when he/she simply asked about a model coming up as `undefined`...